# I'm new to coding, and I have a idea but don't know how to code it

Tags: java, android

I have a idea for my first application. It should be able to write a new note, email the note, post it to Facebook or Twitter, etc. But I don't know how to code it. How can I do it?

Comment: We aren't here to write your software for you. We're here to help answer specific questions you have, and help you overcome specific problems.

Comment: Sure, please deposit AUD$1,000,000 into dodgy_bob@paypal.com and I'll be in contact.

Comment: There's nobody out there that is going to simply teach you how to program this application start to finish. Look around, research API, and even dive into some good examples over at [google.code](http://code.google.com/)

Comment: There are lots of places you can go to take a course to learn how to write programs.  And lots of books.  And lots of online tutorials.  But the chances of someone here offering to teach you ... for free ... is about ZERO.

Comment: +1 Welcome to stackoverflow. sorry to disappoint you, but the people here wont be willing to teach you how to code, we are here to help answer your specific question about the problem you are facing AS you code your android app. Try it by yourself first, then when you encounter a problem, come back here and ask a question about it. we are more than willing to help you. That being said, people here are sometimes a little too harsh towards newcomer..so make sure you read the FAQ first before asking;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to post something on Facebook or Twitter is to use *their* APIs. They don't provide any service that takes emails and creates a status or a tweet.

The reason is trivial: email is very unsecure, you can't identify the originator of an email and such a service would lead to massive spamming.

The only way out would be: send the emails to your own server, then use the Facebook or Twitter API (with **your own** Facebook/Twitter ids) to post the content of the emails.

If the question was more directed towards learning Java or Android - then I agree to commenters and close-voters, teaching languages is out of scope for this Q&A site.

Comment: I think he meant "Email the note, post it on facebook, or post it on twitter."

Comment: @aioobe - Ah, like creating one *note* object and then sending it to various destinations (like email recipient, facebook, twitter) - yes, could be (too) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you start off with a modern high-level language to learn the basics of programming. I would recommend that you start off with either of the following:

- Ruby : http://tryruby.org/ (an interactive tutorial)
- Python : http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Python/PythonIntro.pdf (PDF link)

Comment: Even VB is easier to understand for beginners than Java/C.